# CountDownTimer loop

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

Im trying to make CountDownTimer start few times in a loop but it only starts one time and it should start at least 2 more times,

I've tried for loop and just While(x !=2)

```
        case R.id.tbWait:
            if (waiting.isChecked()){

                int x = 0;
                    do {
                turnOnLights();
                new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000){
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFinish(){
                    turnOffLights();
                }
                }.start();
                    x++;
                    } while (x !=2);

            }

        break;
```

I have tried this aswell but it makes the application not responsive and have to force close it :(

```
        case R.id.tbWait:
            while (waiting.isChecked()){ //Using While instead of if statemnt 

                turnOnLights();
                new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000){
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFinish(){
                    turnOffLights();
                }
                }.start();



            }

        break;
```

Question is how do i loop this when i Toggle the Toggle Button tbWait on?
turnOnLights() then wait 2 seconds then turnOffLights() like the waiting button in the car ? sorry for my bad english and im really new to this ^^
im using AndroidStudio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it the android way, use a Handler!

Make a Handler, a Runnable to turn the lights on, and a Runnable to turn them off:

```
public class YourClass extends ProbablySomeClass{
Handler lightsHandler; //The android.os.Handler one, not the java one
Runnable lightsON = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        if(waiting.isChecked){
            turnLightsOn();
            lightsHandler.postDelayed(lightsOff, 2000);
        }
        else lightsHandler.postDelayed(lightsON, 1000);
    }
}
Runnable lightsOff = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        turnLightsOff();
        lightsHandler.postDelayed(lightsON, 2000);
    }
}
public YourClass(SomeType someParameter){
init(someParameters);    //Whatever your constructor does
lightsHandler = new Handler();
lightsHandler.post(lightsOn)
}
```

Now all your button has to do is un/check that variable, and it will automatically flash every 2 seconds while it is checked.